# md5 algorithm in OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl, md5

I've tried to implement an OpenCL version of the md5 algorithm starting from the version found in the RTF specification, so quickly I've copied the code found [here](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1321.txt) and adapted it to my system (so I've modified the definition of UINT4 to achieve a four byte word). The code works fine when is executed as a normal c program. The only change on the OpenCL implementation is that I've rewritten library function like memset or memcpy. But after the run the md5 digest is not the correct one. Any idea? Maybe there is a problem between little and big endian platforms? Or something related to any trick in OpenCL programming? My code, I repeat, is the same that you found in link (same functions, same structs) and the only change is in the library implementation. Thank you for help!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: Yes, but with CodeXL I cannot inspect arrays.. Without inspecting arrays, the programs works but the result is different (in any cases it happened that run 2 times the program with 2 different results). I've had the same problem with the normal version, and I resolved changing UINT4, but here I don't know how I can resolve..

Comment: I'm curious why you'd want to write an MD5 algorithm in OpenCL? That's for GPUs, right? My ignorance may be showing ...

Comment: It's an university project. I'm going to analyze the new era of password cracking with GPU, and then my teacher asked me to implements a "password cracker" that uses GPU. But now I'm stopped here because if I can't obtain the correct digest I can't go ahead

Comment: When I run a program twice and get different results, usually it's because I didn't initialize some data correctly, or I have a race condition. Have you double checked that your output buffer is reset properly before you run the kernel?

Comment: Output buffer is correctly inizialized to 0 values. But now I check result with printf in the Kernel and with only one work item. So buffers are clear and there are no race conditions

Comment: does it work with global size set to 1?

Comment: No.. The output in byte is different..

Comment: Does someone has any ideas?